# Civimail and Sendgrid limitations and scalability?

Tags: civimail, email, mailserver

Is anyone using Civimail with Sendgrid on a large scale? We have successfully used Civimail for newsletters and it seems to work well. However, on the Sendgrid website they say the SMTP is limited to 100 messages per connection and 1000 recipients. Does his mean Civimail needs to be setup to run a maximum of 1000 emails per cron run? More information here [sendgrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1,000 recipients max? I could see how just about any org will quickly run into that limit!

We end up using CiviSMTP:
http://www.civismtp.com/drupal/

Or SparkPost:
https://www.sparkpost.com

And that's just two examples - there are many other SMTP options.

Comment: Thanks KarinG. Sparkpost seems like a good option and there is a stable CiviCRM extension as well. Cheers.